# Json.NET does not always serialize nested classes

Tags: json.net

I have a class which contains other classes as properties.
I wrote a little test app and my class serialized with Json.NET just fine.
However, when I try to serialize the same class in a much bigger project, I only get the class names of the nested objects in my json string, not the serialized content.
My question: is there any known problem trying to use Json.NET in conjunction with other libraries? My class has protobuf attributes which do not seem to make a difference in my test app.
I am using .NET 4.5.1

Comment: can you share your code please? Obviously project size is not the problem. It seems like the context where you try to serialize doesn't know nothing about those classes....

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?  *is there any known problem trying to use Json.NET in conjunction with other libraries?* is probably too general to get a useful answer, especially since you're not even telling us the libraries that you're using.

Comment: I answered my own question: in my complex app, where the serialization does not work, my class can be displayed in a PropertyGrid. .NET I guess takes this as an invitation to make the default type converter an ExpandableObjectConverter. the JsonTypeReflector does not know about this converter and thus returns true in the query whether this object can be converted to a string which in turns leads to a string contract instead of an object contract.

Comment: When I added ExpandableObjectConverter as a condition in  public static bool CanTypeDescriptorConvertString(Type type, out TypeConverter typeConverter), it works fine